# How do you purge NVIDIA GeForce 7025 drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, purge

How do you remove and purge NVIDIA graphics drivers recommended for installation in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following into the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```